# Translate from Cplex to Python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, cplex, opl

```
using CP;
int numI = 4;
int numP = 3;
int B = 90000000;
// Define sets
range I = 1..numI;
range P = 1..numP;

// Define parameters
int scale=1000;
float v[I][P]=...;
float f[I][P]=...;
float u1[I][I]=...;
float u2[I][I]=...;
float u3[I][I]=...;
float C[I][P]=...;
float MOQ[I][P]=...;
int D[1..1][P]=...; 
int Nmax[P] = [3,2,3];
int Nstr[P]=[2,1,2];
int strat[I][P]=...;
float u[I][I][P];

execute
{
for (var i in I)
    for (var j in I)
        for (var p in P)
            if (p == 1)
                u[i][j][p] = u1[i][j]
            else if (p == 2)
                u[i][j][p] = u2[i][j]
            else
                u[i][j][p] =  u3[i][j];       
              }                
// Define decision variables
dvar boolean y[I][P];
dvar int+ scalex[I][P];
// Decision expressions
dexpr float x[i in I][p in P]=scalex[i][p]/scale;
dexpr float Z = sum(i in I, p in P) (D[1][p]*v[i][p]*x[i][p]) + sum(i in I, p in P) (f[i][p]*y[i][p]);
dexpr float K = sum(i in I, j in I, p in P) u[i][j][p]*x[i][p]*x[j][p];

minimize staticLex(Z, K);

// Define constraints
subject to {
 forall(p in P) {
    sum(i in I) x[i][p] == 1;
    sum(i in I) (D[1][p]*v[i][p]*x[i][p] + f[i][p]*y[i][p]) <= B;
    2 <=  sum(i in I) y[i][p];
    sum(i in I) y[i][p] <= Nmax[p];
    Nstr[p] <= sum(i in I) y[i][p]*strat[i][p];
 }
 forall(i in I, p in P) {
   x[i][p] <= C[i][p]*y[i][p];
   MOQ[i][p]*y[i][p] <= x[i][p];
   0<= x[i][p] <= 1;
   0<= y[i][p] <= 1;
   0<= C[i][p] <= 1;
   0<= MOQ[i][p] <= 1;
   0<= strat[i][p] <= 1;
  }
}

//Python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\final\DATA.xlsx', sheet_name='Set1', header=None)
I in range(1,4)
P in range(1,3)
v={}
for i in I
   for p in P
       v[i][p] = df.iloc[1:4, 2:6].values.tolist()
f = df.iloc[6:9, 2:6].values.tolist()
u1 = df.iloc[12:16, 2:6].values.tolist()
u2 = df.iloc[12:16, 9:13].values.tolist()
u3 = df.iloc[12:16, 15:19].values.tolist()
C = df.iloc[20:23, 2:6].values.tolist()
MOQ = df.iloc[26:29, 2:6].values.tolist()
D = df.iloc[41, 1:4].tolist()
strat = df.iloc[32:35, 2:6].values.tolist()
Nmax = df.iloc[37, 1:4].values.tolist()
Nstr = df.iloc[37, 5:8].values.tolist()
```

The Cplex code has been completed and produces the expected result. But I have problems with Python trying to do the same thing as Cplex. I don't know how to format parameter like in Cplex v[I][P] with Python. The above Pytohn code was written to import data from excel into Python, at that point I was stuck. Please help me fix the unfinished Python code or help it developed more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you could call your OPL CPLEX model from python. Either by using [doopl](https://pypi.org/project/doopl/) or using an [external call from python](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithopl/blob/master/dietpythoncallOPL.py).

If you want to use arrays from dataframes in docplex you can see https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoopandas.py

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
from pandas import *

# Data

dfBuses = pandas.DataFrame({'size': [40,30], 'cost': [500,400]},
                      index = ['bus1', 'bus2'], columns=['size','cost'])

print(dfBuses)

nbKids=300

for b in dfBuses.itertuples():
    print("buses with ",b.size," seats cost ",b.cost)

mdl = Model(name='buses')

#decision variables
mdl.nbBus=mdl.integer_var_dict(dfBuses.itertuples(),name="nbBus")

# Constraint
mdl.add_constraint(mdl.sum(mdl.nbBus[b]*b.size for b in dfBuses.itertuples()) >= nbKids, 'kids')

# Objective
mdl.minimize(mdl.sum(mdl.nbBus[b]*b.cost for b in dfBuses.itertuples()))

mdl.solve()

# Dislay solution
for b in dfBuses.itertuples():
    print(mdl.nbBus[b].solution_value," buses with ",b.size," seats")
```

Comment: like in the example above, how can i write down the size of specific bus 2?